# DST settings for Azure Webjobs in UK Timezone

Tags: azure, cron, scheduled-tasks, azure-webjobs

We have a Triggered webjob running which we want to run once daily at a particular time. We want this job to work at UK Time 2:30 hence cron expression is 0 30 2 * * * but we want to make sure this is not affected by DST. I found this useful [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2015/04/06/changing-the-server-time-zone-on-azure-web-apps/) explaining how we can set-up the **WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE** property in App setting to run jobs according to UK Timezone.

My questions is, How can I identify which Timezone I shall use for **WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE** that will ensure webjos always run at 2:30?

I’m not sure about using “**GMT Standard Time**” as a value for WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE. Any recommendations on this?

What would be best approach to validate the solution works (without waiting for GMT to switch to BST).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "make sure this is not affected by DST"? If you mean that you want it to run exactly every 24 hours regardless of DST, then you should keep the default time zone, which is UTC.

If on the other hand you do want DST to take effect (such that at some point it'll run 23 hours later, and 6 months later 25 hours) then setting the time zone to "GMT Standard Time" will work.

Comment: I want DST not to take effect. thanks David for your prompt reply.
Appreciate your response.